# How to reduce and add value from different element after we check and uncheck using checkbox in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

When I check it can add some values in just 1 element, but I don't know how to add from different element and reduce it.

```js
var y = 1;

function calc() {
  if (document.getElementById("t1").checked) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = z = y + 1;
    if (document.getElementById("t1").reversed) {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = z = y - 1;
    }
  }
  if (document.getElementById("t2").checked) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = z = y + 1;
    if (document.getElementById("t2").reversed) {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = z = y - 1;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="t1" type="checkbox" name="model" value="a1" onclick="calc();">a1
<input id="t2" type="checkbox" name="model" value="a1" onclick="calc();">a2
<h1 id="demo"></h1>
```

Comment: You can just document.getElementById on the elements you want? and use those values for calculation

Comment: Where is `z` defined and used? What is `.reversed` supposed to do?

Comment: Top tip. Use self-commenting variable and function names!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it!
Did you mean this?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<input id="t1" type="checkbox" name="model" value="a1" onclick="calc(this);">a1
<input id="t2" type="checkbox" name="model" value="a1" onclick="calc(this);">a2
<h1 id="demo">0</h1>

<script>
var y = 1;
var z=0;

function calc(e) {
 if(e.checked)
     z = z + 1;
    else
     z = z - 1;
 document.getElementById("demo").innerText = z;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Use something like `if(!e.checked)` if you want to check the checkbox is unchecked and `if(e.checked)` is checked, the symbol `!` is  kinda important :D

Also I have added `this` to your event onclick for each input element for faster get targeted element when click.

```
<input id="t1" type="checkbox" name="model" value="a1" onclick="calc(this);">a1
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the results.  Make it simpler and much better.

Answer (score 0):

if you want z to be used globally then global variable is declared outside the function

Answer (score 0):

With a **counter**. Increment or decrement the value. Assign the value to the `innerHTML` of the output element.

```js
const demo = document.getElementById("demo");

let makeCounter = function() {
  let privateCounter = 0;

  function changeBy(val) {
    privateCounter += val;
  }

  return {
    value: function() {
      return privateCounter;
    },
    increment: function() {
      changeBy(1);
    },
    decrement: function() {
      changeBy(-1);
    }
  }
};

let myCounter = makeCounter();

function changeValue(el) {
  el.checked ? myCounter.increment() : myCounter.decrement();
  demo.innerHTML = myCounter.value();
}
```

```html
<input id="t1" type="checkbox" name="model" value="a1" onclick="changeValue(this);">a1
<input id="t2" type="checkbox" name="model" value="a1" onclick="changeValue(this);">a2
<h1 id="demo"></h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach without any variables. The count is re-established every time a checkbox is clicked:

```js
const qs=s=>document.querySelector(s),
  qsa=s=>document.querySelectorAll(s);

qs("body").addEventListener("click",ev=>ev.target.name==='model'
  ? qs('#demo').innerText=qsa('input:checked').length
  : 0);
```

```html
<input id="t1" type="checkbox" name="model" value="a1">a1
<input id="t2" type="checkbox" name="model" value="a2">a2
<h1 id="demo">0</h1>
```

I defined `qs()` and `qsa()` as shortcut functions to improve the readability of the code.

Comment: Thank you very much for the results. Make it simpler and much better.